# python - search for an element inside a dictionary inside a list

Tags: python

My data structure looks like this:

```
  - testSet: a list of records in the test set, where each record
             is a dictionary containing values for each attribute
```

And in each record there is an element named "ID". I now want to search for a record inside `testSet` by an ID value. So when I'm given an ID = 230 I want to return the record that it's ID element equals 230.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
next((x for x in testSet if x["ID"] == 230), None)
```

This will return the first item with that ID or `None` if it's not found.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
for record in testSet:
    if record['ID'] == 230:
        return record
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
set = [{'ID': 50}, {'ID': 80}]

def find_set(id):
    return [elem for elem in set if elem['ID'] == id]
```

This will return all items with the specified ID. If you only want the first one, add [0] (after checking if it exists, e.g.:

```
def find_set(id):
    elems = [elem for elem in set if elem['ID'] == id]
    return elems[0] if elems else None
```